# How to count the number of noun appeared in a paragraph with Google's NL api using ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, count, google-cloud-nl

Trying to count the number of noun appeared in a paragraph with Google's NL api using ruby.

Been looking up the document, couldn't find how to do this.

Work out a solution last night

```
text = 'xxxxxxxxxx'
response = language.analyze_syntax content: text, type: :PLAIN_TEXT

sentences = response.sentences
tokens    = response.tokens
x= tokens.count

a = Array.new(x-1)

for i in 1..x
    a[i-1] = tokens[i-1].part_of_speech.tag.to_s
end
for i in 1..x
    if a[i-1] == 'NOUN' 

    num= num+1
    end
end
```

still wondering if there exist something like (tokens.noun.count ?) in the nl api https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/analyzing-syntax#language-syntax-string-ruby.

Comment: just trying to find a solution

Comment: What have you tried so far? StackOverflow is not a free code writing service (that's why you're getting downvoted); you need to show a bit more effort. What libraries are you using? What documentation are you referencing? Do you have a partial solution? An incorrect result? An error message? Anything at all?

Comment: Ok.  I just come up with a partial solution . I will put it on the origin post.

Comment: At a glance... `tokens.select { |t| t.part_of_speech.tag.to_s == 'NOUN' }.count`? Only the first 4 lines of your code are needed; the rest can be deleted. (And I assume you're using the `sentences` for something else, further down?)

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot. And yes, I need sentences for something else :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on your example, you could count the number of `NOUN`s like so:

```
text = 'xxxxxxxxxx'
response = language.analyze_syntax content: text, type: :PLAIN_TEXT

tokens = response.tokens

tokens.count { |t| t.part_of_speech.tag.to_s == 'NOUN' }
```

Note that in ruby, it is very common style to use *iterators* like this, rather than defining temporary variables and using `for` loops. (In fact, [you should *almost never* find a need to use `for` loops in ruby!](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#no-for-loops))

This clean, concise syntax is one of the biggest appeals of the ruby language. Very often, you can obtain a desired result in one line of code like that rather than all of this temporary array and index counter declarations.

Comment: thanks. and the [ruby-style-guide](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#no-for-loops)  is really helpful.